# Rotate a UIImageView as you drag the image around screen

Tags: uiimageview, rotation

I have a project where you drage a UIImageView around the screen to complete different functions, however the actual image in the view is static and I actually want it to rotate to the angle that you drag, so if you drag the UIImage left I want the image to rotate to the left and stay there, if you then drag up the image rotates to the up position etc etc.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting project. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a rotation to the view transform:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleInRadians);
```

You can remove the transform at any time too:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for the post, I have the following code, I just want the "ship" to face the same way as the drag, if that makes sense, not sure where to put the code:

Comment: -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
 CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
 ship.center = location; 
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [self ifCollided];
}